# How can I share a simple string value (config) between two web applications asp.net and asp.net core in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

How can I share a simple string value (config) between two web applications `asp.net` and `asp.net core` in IIS?

I don't want to use cookies

Comment: Is this value different for different users?

Comment: No that's not a user setting, it's just an application setting

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we could achieve this in the following ways,

1. Web service, such as WCF.
   One application is used to create and host WCF service. Another application is used to consume the service.
   Create and host the service in a web application by using the default WCF project template in Visual Studio or directly adding an SVC file to the current web project.
   [image]
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis
   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d56e1/how-to-create-and-consume-wcf-services/
   **Consume the service.**
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide
2. Shared sessions stored in the same database.
   [Passing session data between ASP.NET web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278512/passing-session-data-between-asp-net-web-applications)
   [Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service)
   Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.